# How to consume (call, execute) WebApi (PUT,POST : .NET 6.0) from Console/XUnit Test (again .NET 6.0)

Tags: c#, .net

I have 4 methods:
2 x PUT and 2 x POST. With one complex parameter (POCO class) or three simple parameters:

```
    public class PocoRequest
    {
        [JsonPropertyName("arg01")]
        public string Arg01 { get; set; }
        [JsonPropertyName("arg02")]
        public Guid Arg02 { get; set; }
        [JsonPropertyName("arg03")]
        public string Arg03 { get; set; }
    }

    [ApiController]
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    public class PostPlainController : ControllerBase
    {
        [HttpPost(Name = "PostPlainRequest")]
        public IActionResult PutPlainRequest(string arg01, Guid arg02, string arg03)
        {
            var middle = arg02.ToString();
            var first = middle.ToLower();
            var second = middle.ToUpper();
            return arg01 == first && arg03 == second ? Ok() : NotFound();
        }
    }
    [ApiController]
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    public class PostPocoController : ControllerBase
    {
        [HttpPost(Name = "PostPocoRequest")]
        public IActionResult PutPocoRequest(PocoRequest request)
        {
            var middle = request.Arg02.ToString();
            var first = middle.ToLower();
            var second = middle.ToUpper();
            return request.Arg01 == first && request.Arg03 == second ? Ok() : NotFound();
        }
    }
    [ApiController]
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    public class PutPlainController : ControllerBase
    {
        [HttpPut(Name = "PutPlainRequest")]
        public IActionResult PutPlainRequest(string arg01, Guid arg02, string arg03)
        {
            var middle = arg02.ToString();
            var first = middle.ToLower();
            var second = middle.ToUpper();
            return arg01 == first && arg03 == second ? Ok() : NotFound();
        }
    }
    [ApiController]
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    public class PutPocoController : ControllerBase
    {
        [HttpPut(Name = "PutPocoRequest")]
        public IActionResult PutPocoRequest(PocoRequest request)
        {
            var middle = request.Arg02.ToString();
            var first = middle.ToLower();
            var second = middle.ToUpper();
            return request.Arg01 == first && request.Arg03 == second ? Ok() : NotFound();
        }
    }
```

And tests:

```
public class PostUnitTest
    {
        [Fact]
        public void PostPlainPositiveTest()
        {
            PostPlainPositiveTestAsync().Wait();
        }
        private async Task PostPlainPositiveTestAsync()
        {
            var url = "https://localhost:7095/api/PostPlain";
            using var apiClient = new HttpClient();
            var str = "0a4b9957-4505-45df-b593-47d365b5d25a";
            var value = new Dictionary<string, string>
            {
                { "arg01", str.ToLower() },
                { "arg02", Guid.Parse(str).ToString() },
                { "arg03", str.ToUpper() }
            };
            var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(value);
            var res = await apiClient.PostAsync(url, content);
            Assert.Equal(HttpStatusCode.OK, res.StatusCode);
        }
        [Fact]
        public void PostPlainNegativeTest()
        {
            PostPlainNegativeTestAsync().Wait();
        }
        private async Task PostPlainNegativeTestAsync()
        {
            var url = "https://localhost:7095/api/PostPlain";
            using var apiClient = new HttpClient();
            var str = "0a4b9957-4505-45df-b593-47d365b5d25a";
            var value = new Dictionary<string, string>
            {
                { "arg01", str.ToUpper() },
                { "arg02", Guid.Parse(str).ToString() },
                { "arg03", str.ToUpper() }
            };
            var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(value);
            var res = await apiClient.PostAsync(url, content);
            Assert.Equal(HttpStatusCode.NotFound, res.StatusCode);
        }
        [Fact]
        public void PostPocoPositiveTest()
        {
            PostPocoPositiveTestAsync().Wait();
        }
        private async Task PostPocoPositiveTestAsync()
        {
            var url = "https://localhost:7095/api/PostPoco";
            using var apiClient = new HttpClient();
            var str = "0a4b9957-4505-45df-b593-47d365b5d25a";
            var value = new PocoRequest
            {
                Arg01 = str.ToLower(),
                Arg02 = Guid.Parse(str),
                Arg03 = str.ToUpper()
            };
            var content = JsonContent.Create(value);
            var res = await apiClient.PostAsync(url, content);
            Assert.Equal(HttpStatusCode.OK, res.StatusCode);
        }
        [Fact]
        public void PostPocoNegativeTest()
        {
            PostPocoNegativeTestAsync().Wait();
        }
        private async Task PostPocoNegativeTestAsync()
        {
            var url = "https://localhost:7095/api/PostPoco";
            using var apiClient = new HttpClient();
            var str = "0a4b9957-4505-45df-b593-47d365b5d25a";
            var value = new PocoRequest
            {
                Arg01 = str.ToUpper(),
                Arg02 = Guid.Parse(str),
                Arg03 = str.ToUpper()
            };
            var content = JsonContent.Create(value);
            var res = await apiClient.PostAsync(url, content);
            Assert.Equal(HttpStatusCode.NotFound, res.StatusCode);
        }
    }
```

(PutUnitTest - tests PUT actions - looks similar).

Api with single complex parameter works perfect (from Swagger and XUnit runner).
But I don't know how to consume (call) PUT/POST with multiple parameters from XUnit - Swagger works as expected.

I am using recommended HttpClient.

I have existing PUT/POST actions with multiple parameters. Migration to single request class is possible but painfull.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with client (consuming) code.
There is problem with controllers.
Plain controllers ie:
`(string arg01, Guid arg02, string arg03)`
have to be changed to:
`([FromForm] string arg01, [FromForm] Guid arg02, [FromForm] string arg03)`